# Bathtub drain not draining at all. New remodel

Tags: plumbing

I recently remodeled a bathroom in a doublewide home.  The old bathtub had a drain in the center with a 90 degree pipe right under that ran to the corner of the tub where the vent pipe was then under the floor.  I put a new tub in with the drain in the end.  I put a trap right under the pipe where the water leaves the tube and goes back under the floor.  The vent pipe is about 4 inches past the trap. the vent pipe is only 4 feet tall cause I haven't hooked it to the old pipe yet.  The drain is not stopped up down the line either.  The tub will not drain at all.  The old tub did not have a trap in the bathtub.  I am not experienced in this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen!  Is the output of the trap below the height of the drain?  Have you tried fishing the pipe or sticking a cheap USB camera down there?  Do you have access to the pipes on the underside still?  What do you mean not stopped up down the line? if you pour water down the vent does it drain?  Are you sure the drain plug is correctly installed?

Comment: Forget any test plugs?What tubing are you referring to "water leaves the tube"? Was the drain pipe sloped?